# Centering UIView in LoadView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Was just wondering how you all go about centering a subview in the viewcontrollers main view while in loadView. I know the code for how to center it, but the problem is, while in loadView, the viewcontrollers main view frame is incorrect since it hasn't resized it yet to fit in between my tabbar and navbar. So if I center a subview within it, it won't be centered by the time the view appears. I did a little experimenting and it seems the viewcontrollers view sets its frame correctly somewhere after viewWillAppear is called and before viewDidAppear is called. Anyone have any insight on how I can accomplish this correctly while in loadView? (overriding layoutSubviews isn't an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the subview always at the center, you should set the correct frame of your subview in either `-viewDidLoad` or `-loadView`, after the `view` property is correctly set, and set its `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.

Also remember to set your superview's `autoresizesSubviews` to `YES`, either from xib or your initialization code.

Comment: When you implement the view programmatically in loadView, the correct view frame is still not set in viewDidLoad. Also, how is setting those auto resize masks going to help, those for resizing, not repositioning.

Comment: Actually, the `autoresizingMask` is used both for resizing and positioning views. This answer is correct.

Comment: Just set its frame in viewDidLoad. Toggling UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight would cause it resize. Just try to imagine the meaning of these terms, or see the Autoresizing graph in the xib panel's size inspector, play with it.

Comment: You son of a gun, you were absolutely right and all I did was fight you over this. I changed the autoresizingmasks that you mentioned to the subview in loadView and it worked fine. Didn't have to set the frame in viewDidLoad. Could you change your answer to reflect this and I'll mark it correct?